# Joomla (ACL) with menu item in Joomla! 1.5 version

Tags: php, joomla, acl, access-control

There's many articles I used to manage.
And then, there's also many users inside many groups.

I then make a specific menu items for the articles accordingly.
But here comes the case:

How to make a menu item to be shown for a specific person inside a specific group only?

Because I found there's a [paid version of Community ACL.](http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.corephp.com/joomla-products/community-acl.html&rct=j&q=community%20acl&ei=U7gfToeBHcLorAfR0ezxAQ&usg=AFQjCNEyg-88-HQFhhAYivCIVRWRak72qQ&sig2=asCPiDY146fYiTvp3vpMog&cad=rja) But i didn't see the opensource version that is no need to change the joomla core files.

Is there anybody here knowing the way out?

Answer (score 0):

I have to maintain about a half dozen Joomla1.5 sites, and have had great success with [noixACL](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/7010)